# How does a list or a tuple becomes empty if multiply by a negative value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How does a list or a tuple becomes empty if multiply by a negative value?

For example:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3] * 2
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [1,2,3] * -1
>>> c
[]
>>> d = [1,2,3] * -2
>>> d
[]
```

Comment: Interesting, but you have to ask yourself what do you mean by repeating negative times ...

Comment: Yes, multiply by -1 time is going to just remove it and then it's just empty..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is documented [oddly deep inside the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> In the latter case, sequence repetition is performed; **a negative repetition factor yields an empty sequence**.

Emphasis mine.

So it does this because this is the documented behaviour. It likely just calls `clear` on the list, or does something equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

## Documentations

As people answered before me, the standard behavior of Python defined in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> In the latter case, sequence repetition is performed; a negative repetition factor yields an empty sequence.

---

## Source Code

If you wonder why it happens, you can follow CPython's source code:

Start with the code in [abstract.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/abstract.c):

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Multiply(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    PyObject *result = binary_op1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_multiply));
    ...
        if  (mv && mv->sq_repeat) {
            return sequence_repeat(mv->sq_repeat, v, w);
        }
        else if (mw && mw->sq_repeat) {
            return sequence_repeat(mw->sq_repeat, w, v);
        }
    ...
}
```

Then, on [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c87a667bb367ace1de6bd1577fdb4f66947da52/Objects/listobject.c):

```c
static PySequenceMethods list_as_sequence = {
    ...
    (ssizeargfunc)list_repeat,                  /* sq_repeat */
    ...
}
```

Jump to [list_repeat](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c87a667bb367ace1de6bd1577fdb4f66947da52/Objects/listobject.c#L558):

```c
static PyObject *
list_repeat(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t n)
{
    ...
    if (n < 0)
        n = 0;
    ...
    if (size == 0)
        return PyList_New(0);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain you with an example.

If you multiply the list [1,2,3] by 3(for example), it means the new list will be of the size of the original list multiplied by 3. So in this example, the number of elements of the list will be 9. Kindly note that there are 3 copies of the same elements in the list.

```
c = [1,2,4] *3
print(c)
[1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4]
```

So now if you are multiplying the list with a negative number then it means that there are a negative number of elements present in the list. That is there are no elements present in the list.

Hope this will help you.